# How to determine the hierarchy of a record with SQL or JPA

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a system to determine menu links hierarchy and build the breadcrumb. I have 2 tables: `Voce` and `Voci`.

`Voce` is both the menu link name and the page title name. `Voci` represents the hierarchy of `Voce`. Every `Voce` can have another `Voce` as son (here you don't see the relative code, anyway I use JPA to bind a Voce to many Voci). For example, this is the hierarchy of the page/link "add many items": `menu --> manage menu --> add many items.`

```
 ----------
|         |
|        \/           Voce
|       -----------------------
|       |id |      name       |    
|       -----------------------
|       |1  |menu             |   
|      -----------------------
|       |2  |manage menu      |  
|       -----------------------
|       |3  |add single item  |
|       -----------------------
|       |4  |add many items   |
|       -----------------------
|
|_____________
        |     |
        |     |
Voci    |     |
-----------------
|id |father|son |
 ----------------
|1  |  1   |  2 |
 ----------------
|2  |  2   |  3 |
-----------------
|3  |  2   |  4 |
-----------------
```

My question is: how can I determine the hierarchy of the link "add many items" in order to build the relative breadcrumb? I have to determine the hierarchy starting from the last element ("add many items"), that is the only data I have.

Is there a single query or a JPA way (I'm using Spring MVC and Hibernate)that allows me to know all the `Voci` records that determine the hierarchy of the link "add many items".

I hope to be clear.

Thank you

Comment: What database are you using ? In Oracle database, the `CONNECT BY PRIOR` statement could help you. Else, you'll have do it in Java/JPA fetching the father, then the father of the father and so on until father is null (or the root).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the closure table pattern. In addition to the parent and child IDs a closure table also contains a `depth` column. For each depth all items in the hierarchy are added.

```
|parent|child|depth 
|1     |1    |0 
|1     |2    |1
|1     |3    |2
|1     |4    |3

|2     |2    |0 
|2     |3    |1
|2     |4    |2

|3     |3    |0 
|3     |4    |1

|4     |4    |0
```

The only thing you have to do now is to query all entries where the child is the selected menu and order them by depth:

```
select parent from Voci where child = 4 order by depth

returns 4,3,2,1

-> select * from Voce where id in (select parent from Voci where child = 4 order by depth)
   or a correspondent JPA Query
```

There are several other patterns for storing hierarchies. Some databases support (vendor-specific) recursive queries, but the usage of simple parent IDs - and Voci is essentially nothing else - is considered an anti-pattern.